# If you have to restore an iPhone to "factory" (the latest iOS), can you choose which backup to use?

Tags: iphone, ios

Suppose I have an iPhone 7 Plus, an iPhone X, and iPad Pro, and the iPhone 7 Plus has to be restored to factory (the latest iOS), because the iOS 13 upgrade fail to boot up the iPhone.

In this case, if there are iCloud backups for the iPhone 7 Plus, an iPhone X, and iPad Pro, can I choose which one to use to restore as much as possible? (they all use the same iCloud account).

What if the backup for iPhone 7 Plus cannot be made because it is too big, then can you choose to restore from iPhone X or iPad Pro, so that at least all your phone contacts and Notes content can be restored?

Comment: It's been a while but I *believe* that when restoring you are given the option to choose which backup regardless of whether  it is an iCloud backup or a local one on your Mac/PC...